# Create runtime predicate with information from Expression<Func<T, object>>

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Assuming the following code

```
private readonly T entity;

public bool HasUnique<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> property, IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
}
```

Where `property` is a property expression of `T` entity.

**How to check if there is any element in `entities` with the same property value as `entity` has, while property is resolved from given property expression?**

By now, I can get property name and its value from entity

The problem seems to be how to set up and execute at runtime a predicate? Something like

```
Func<T, bool> predicate = // build a predicate
var isUnique = !entities.Any(predicate);
```

The usage would be like this

```
var isUnique = HasUnique<Person>(p => p.Name, people);
```

Comment: You don't need to edit the question's title to say "solved" when you accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to figure out what the word "Unique" has to do with what you described, and your example usage doesn't involve any entity to compare the contents of `people` to, but I think you're going for something like this?

```
public static bool HasUnique<T>(this T referenceItem, Func<T, object> property, 
                                IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    var referenceProperty = property(referenceItem);
    return entities.Any(e => property(e) == referenceProperty);
}
```

or maybe this:

```
public static bool HasUnique<T>(this T referenceItem, Func<T, object> property, 
                                IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    var referenceProperty = property(referenceItem);
    return entities.Any(e => property(e).Equals(referenceProperty));
}
```

Or even this:

```
public static bool HasUnique<T, TProp>(this T referenceItem, Func<T, TProp> property, 
                                IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    var referenceProperty = property(referenceItem);
    return entities.Any(e => property(e).Equals(referenceProperty));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an `Expression<Func<T,object>>`? Because it can be achieved with just `Func<T,object>`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqPlayground
{
    class Program
    {
        public class UniqueChecker<T>
        {
            public bool HasUnique<T>(Func<T, object> property, IEnumerable<T> entities)
            {
                var uniqueDict = new Dictionary<object, bool>();
                foreach (var entity1 in entities)
                {
                    var key = property(entity1);
                    if (uniqueDict.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        uniqueDict[key] = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        uniqueDict.Add(key, true);
                    }
                }
                return uniqueDict.Values.All(b => b);
            }
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var people = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person {Name = "Chris"},
                new Person {Name = "Janet"},
                new Person {Name = "John"},
                new Person {Name = "Janet"},
            };

            var checker = new UniqueChecker<Person>();


            Console.WriteLine("Are names unique? {0}",checker.HasUnique(person => person.Name, people));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Expression redundance